# DateTime ticks constructor clocks go forward potential bug

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

There is a [DateTime constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_DateTime__ctor_System_Int64_System_DateTimeKind_) which allows you to construct it with a `long ticks` and a `DateTimeKind`. The documentation indicates that the ticks represent the time since a fixed point. The `kind` indicates whether it represents a local, UTC, or unspecified DateTime.

The problem relates specifically to when times when the clocks go forward. Let's start by picking such a time (I'm in the UK, and this is the date when clocks went forward this year):

```
        var original = new DateTime(2021, 3, 28, 1, 20, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
        long ticks = original.Ticks;
```

I wanted the local time for the given value of `ticks`, so I was doing this:

```
        var createdAsLocal = new DateTime(ticks, DateTimeKind.Local);
```

However, this ends up giving me an *invalid* DateTime... it gives me a DateTime of "2021-03-28 01:20:00" with Kind set to Local. That's invalid in the sense that it cannot actually exist, because as far as Local time is concerned, at 1am it becomes 2am, there are no local times between the two... the framework doesn't complain, and the program has no problem until I try to do certain things with that value.

It looks like I *should* have been doing this:

```
        var createdAsUtc = new DateTime(ticks, DateTimeKind.Utc);
        var createdAsUtcThenMadeLocal = createdAsUtc.ToLocalTime();
```

which gives me a different value. So it seems to me that using this constructor with anything other than `DateTimeKind.Utc` is unlikely to be robust.

Perhaps I've misunderstood something. Can anyone clarify why `createdAsLocal` has a different value than `createdAsUtcThenMadeLocal`?

Comment: when you assign `createdAsLocal`, what you'd want to say is this: tell me what 2021-03-28 01:20:00 Utc is in local time (whatever time zone properties that represents). But what you're actually doing in `new DateTime(ticks, DateTimeKind.Local);` is "interpret the ticks value as a local date" and that's not what it is.

Comment: @CeeMcSharpface The documentation says that ticks is a value since a fixed point in time. So the ticks value I have supplied represents the time at 1:20am UTC, which I think you would agree the same value **also** represents the time at 2:20am Local time... so that _is_ what it is.

Comment: A DateTime is always stored in a computer as UTC.  The when you convert the DateTime to a string the local timezone setting is used. So just use new DateTime(ticks) without the local parameter.

Comment: @jdweng Again... no, not true.

Comment: @jdweng For clarity: I am not converting the value to a string anywhere in my code. I have only used quotations around the value in the question as a simplistic way to represent the value to people on this forum (rather than supply the value of each of a dozen different properties, which would be hard to read) - perhaps that's my mistake, but it's only a 5 line MCVE, so I'm not asking a lot for someone to try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help, everyone. I need to pull together the responses from 3 people to form the complete answer.

The crux of my misunderstanding here revolves around the documentation using the description of `ticks` as:

> "A date and time expressed in the number of 100-nanosecond intervals
> that have elapsed since January 1, 0001 at 00:00:00.000 in the
> Gregorian calendar."

I was making what is clearly a common mistake of thinking that the value of `ticks` would be the same whichever timezone or daylight-savings-time you were in. For example, I had *incorrectly* said in response to a comment from @CeeMcSharpface:

> the ticks value I have supplied represents the time at 1:20am UTC,
> which I think you would agree the same value also represents the time
> at 2:20am Local time...

*That* was where my misunderstanding lay. Effectively I was mistakenly thinking it was a UTC value. The ticks value *isn't* the same, even if the two times represent the same "point in time".

As explained by the second attempt at an answer from @ManishDalal, which boils down to:

```
        var utc = new DateTime(2021, 3, 28, 1, 20, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
        var utcToLocal = utc.ToLocalTime();
        Console.WriteLine("UTC Ticks . . . . . : " + utc.Ticks);
        Console.WriteLine("UTC To Local Ticks  : " + utcToLocal.Ticks);
```

and demonstrates that the ticks value for a local time is different than the ticks for the UTC time that it represents. Effectively under the hood, the `ticks` is just being used as a mathematical way of storing all the different parts of a date&time value.

So @CeeMcSharpface was correct in saying

> what you're actually doing in new DateTime(ticks, DateTimeKind.Local);
> is "interpret the ticks value as a local date" and that's not what it
> is.

which is also what @Charlieface was saying: that if you choose to use the constructor with `ticks` and `kind`, there is an assumption that the **pair** of values you are supplying "go together" (which is not clear from the documentation of the `kind` parameter). In my case, they were did not go together, because I had a UTC ticks value that I wanted to be represented as a Local time, so as I said in the question, I *should* have been doing:

```
    var createdAsUtc = new DateTime(ticks, DateTimeKind.Utc);
    var createdAsUtcThenMadeLocal = createdAsUtc.ToLocalTime();
```

Answer (score 1):

**Corrected Response below**

<strike>The DateTime object contains the time in your system's current time zone.</strike>

When you created the `original` `DateTime` type using `var original = new DateTime(2021, 3, 28, 1, 20, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);`, you specified that the time you are passing is a UTC time by specifying `DateTimeKind.Utc`, but the value contained in `original` is in your current time zone (+1:00 as per your time zone).

If you want to access the same UTC time, you should call `original.ToUniversalTime()` and that will give you the UTC date time. Now you can get the ticks from this.

```
var utcDt = original.ToUniversalTime();
var utcTicks = utcDt.Ticks;
```

---

---

**EDIT:**

*Correction and sample code after the OP's comment that `ToUniversalTime()` does not have any affect on Ticks value and I identified my mistake that it should be `ToLocalTime()` not `ToUniversalTime()`*

---

The `DateTime` value contains the time specified in UTC format. To get the local time you call `ToLocalTime()` like

```
var dtLocal = original.ToLocalTime();
var localTicks = dtLocal.Ticks;
```

```
using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var dtUtc = new DateTime(2021, 3, 28, 1, 20, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
        var dtLocal = new DateTime(2021, 3, 28, 1, 20, 0, DateTimeKind.Local);

        var utc2local = dtUtc.ToLocalTime();
        var utc2localTicks = utc2local.Ticks;
        
        var nowUtc = DateTime.UtcNow;
        var nowLocal = DateTime.Now;

        long utcTicks = dtUtc.Ticks;
        long localTicks = dtLocal.Ticks;
        
        var utc2utc = dtUtc.ToUniversalTime();
        long utc2utcTicks = utc2utc.Ticks;
        
        string fmt = "dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss";

        Console.WriteLine("«new» UTC Time :  " + dtUtc.ToString(fmt));
        Console.WriteLine("«new» Local Time: " + dtLocal.ToString(fmt));
        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine("UTC To Local Time : " + utc2local.ToString(fmt));

        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine("UTC Ticks . . . . . : " + utcTicks.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("Local Ticks . . . . : " + localTicks.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("UTC To Local Ticks  : " + utc2localTicks.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine("UTC to UTC Time : " + utc2utc.ToString(fmt));
        Console.WriteLine("UTC to UTC Ticks: " + utc2utcTicks.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("");

        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine("Now UTC :  " + nowUtc.ToString(fmt));
        Console.WriteLine("Now Local: " + nowLocal.ToString(fmt));
        
        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine("---------------------------------------------------------");
        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine("");
        
        TimeZone ctz = TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone;

        DateTime dtNow = DateTime.Now;
        DateTime dtNowUtc = ctz.ToUniversalTime(dtNow);
        TimeSpan tsOffset = ctz.GetUtcOffset(dtNow);

        string strTime = ((tsOffset.TotalMinutes < 0) ? "-": "+");
        strTime += tsOffset.Hours.ToString("D2") + ":" + tsOffset.Minutes.ToString("D2");

        Console.WriteLine("Current Time Zone: " + ctz.StandardName + " (" +  strTime + ")" );
    }
}
```

The output on my machine (+5:30 IST) is:

```
«new» UTC Time :  28-Mar-2021 01:20:00
«new» Local Time: 28-Mar-2021 01:20:00

UTC To Local Time : 28-Mar-2021 06:50:00


UTC Ticks . . . . . : 637524912000000000
Local Ticks . . . . : 637524912000000000
UTC To Local Ticks  : 637525110000000000

UTC to UTC Time : 28-Mar-2021 01:20:00
UTC to UTC Ticks: 637524912000000000


Now UTC :  30-Jul-2021 22:09:07
Now Local: 31-Jul-2021 03:39:07


----------------------------------------------------------------


Current Time Zone: India Standard Time (+05:30)
```

*Here one can notice that `UTC Ticks` and `UTC To Local Ticks` values are different.*

---

The same code is available on [dotnetfiddle.net](https://dotnetfiddle.net/2IFhxD), but there Ticks do not show any difference as their server is already on UTC Time Zone.

Comment: `ToUniversalTime()` on a DateTime whose `Kind` is `Utc` returns the same value, and the `utcTicks` in your answer ends up containing the same value as `ticks` in the question, so has absolutely no effect whatsoever.

Comment: @Richardissimo: I have corrected my mistake and added a sample program. HTH.

Answer (score 1):

**That constructor is just that: a constructor.** It's not designed to do any conversion, it's only designed to artificially construct a known `ticks` value with an associated `DateTimeKind`. It's assumed that you know it's a valid value.

[The code for the constructor](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/datetime.cs,165) (with a little validation) is simply:

```cs
this.dateData = ((UInt64)ticks | ((UInt64)kind << KindShift));
```

---

If you want to convert to local time then yes, you will need to use `ToLocalTime()`, for which you need a pre-constructed *UTC* time to convert.

Note though, that conversion to local time in that fashion may not have been valid at that time. It uses the *current* settings for calculating time zones, not the way time zones were calculated then. The only way to have a valid local time is to use `DateTimeOffset`.